# Python web scraping table with sub headings

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am trying to extract some information from a table which appears on various webpages (My apologies for not disclosing the webpage).

```
<table class="toccolours" style="font-size: 85%;">
 <tbody><tr>
 <th colspan="8" style="background-color: #ccf; color: #000080; text-align:center;"><b>First sub-class</b></th>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Info1</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px;"><a title="Object 1">Object 1</a></td>
 <td style="text-align:center;padding-right:5px">Info 2</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px"><a title="Object 2">Object 2</a></td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Info 3</td>
 <td style="text-align:center;">Info 4</td>
 <td style="text-align:center;">Info 5</td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <th colspan="8" style="background-color: #ccf; color: #000080; text-align:center;"><b>Second sub-class</b></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Info11</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px;"><a title="Object 11">Object 11</a></td>
 <td style="text-align:center;padding-right:5px">Info 22</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px"><a title="Object 22">Object 22</a></td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Info 33</td>
 <td style="text-align:center;">Info 44</td>
 <td style="text-align:center;">Info 55</td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th colspan="8" style="background-color: #ccf; color: #000080; text-align:center;"><b>Third sub-class</b></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Info 111</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px;"><a title="Object 111">Object 111</a></td>
 <td style="text-align:center;padding-right:5px">Info 222</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Object 222</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Info 333</td>
 <td style="text-align:center;">Info 444</td>
 <td style="text-align:center;">Info 555</td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody></table>
```

Where the table essentially looks like the following:
[image: Original Table]

**Image 1**

The problem is that both the the sub-classes and the number of rows for each subclass may change. So for example, the First sub-class in some cases may have 1 items, Second sub-class may have 3 items and the third sub-class may have 2 items. Additionally I may also get a table with only sub-class 1 and 2.

For example:

[image: Other example 1]

**Image 2**

OR

[image: Other example 2]

**Image 3**

are also possible.

I want to get the data in a format so that the sub-class value appears alongside the relevant info rows in the following format (following image 1):

[image: desired solution]

**Image 4**

However I am a little stuck with how to achieve this on python since the table headings are not separate classes under which each row item appears. I can call a webpage on using web driver and extract the page source using beautiful soup. However, I could not figure out how to assign the sub-classes to the rows  in this case (especially since the info rows do not appear as an element of the subclass row but merely as a new row of the table).

As of now, I can use **.find_all('tr')** to get all the rows of the tables. However since the sub-classes and the number of rows are not uniform across the (500 or so tables), I cannot seem to get my head around to getting the data. Any help would be appreciated.

p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just process your HTML row by row:

```
b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
data = {}
current = None
for row in b.find_all('tr'):
    if row.find_all('th'):
        # this is a header
        current = row.find_all('th')[0].text
    else:
        # this is not a header, therefore is data under the last header seen
        data[current] = row.find_all('td') # do whatever processing you need to do here, you did't specify
```

If you need to preserve the order of your headers, instead of a dict, use a list of lists:

```
data = []
headers = []

for row in b.find_all('tr'):
    if row.find_all('th'):
        # this is a header
        headers.append(row.find_all('th')[0].text)
        data.append([])
    else:
        # this is not a header, therefore is data under the last header seen
        data[-1].append(row.find_all('td'))
print zip(headers,data)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I used `lxml` hope it fits with your problem

```
from lxml import etree

html_body = """
<table class="toccolours" style="font-size: 85%;">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
    <th colspan="8" style="background-color: #ccf; color: #000080; text-align:center;"><b>First sub-class</b></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Info1</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px;"><a title="Object 1">Object 1</a></td>
 <td style="text-align:center;padding-right:5px">Info 2</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px"><a title="Object 2">Object 2</a></td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Info 3</td>
 <td style="text-align:center;">Info 4</td>
 <td style="text-align:center;">Info 5</td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <th colspan="8" style="background-color: #ccf; color: #000080; text-align:center;"><b>Second sub-class</b></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Info11</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px;"><a title="Object 11">Object 11</a></td>
 <td style="text-align:center;padding-right:5px">Info 22</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px"><a title="Object 22">Object 22</a></td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Info 33</td>
 <td style="text-align:center;">Info 44</td>
 <td style="text-align:center;">Info 55</td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th colspan="8" style="background-color: #ccf; color: #000080; text-align:center;"><b>Third sub-class</b></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Info 111</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px;"><a title="Object 111">Object 111</a></td>
 <td style="text-align:center;padding-right:5px">Info 222</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Object 222</td>
 <td style="padding-right:5px">Info 333</td>
 <td style="text-align:center;">Info 444</td>
 <td style="text-align:center;">Info 555</td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody></table>
"""

tableData = {}

tree = etree.fromstring(html_body, parser=etree.HTMLParser())
for i in tree.xpath("//tr/th[@colspan]"):
    className = i.getchildren()[0].text
    tableData[className] = []

    parentTag = i.getparent()
    tableBody = parentTag.getnext().xpath('td')
    for cell in tableBody:
        if cell.text:
            tableData[className].append(cell.text)
        else:
            child_tag = cell.getchildren()
            if child_tag:
                tableData[className].append(child_tag[0].text)

print tableData
```

Output:

```
>>> {'Second sub-class': ['Info11', 'Object 11', 'Info 22', 'Object 22', 'Info 33', 'Info 44', 'Info 55'], 'First sub-class': ['Info1', 'Object 1', 'Info 2', 'Object 2', 'Info 3', 'Info 4', 'Info 5'], 'Third sub-class': ['Info 111', 'Object 111', 'Info 222', 'Object 222', 'Info 333', 'Info 444', 'Info 555']}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.